# Premeasures on Algebras

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, outer-measure

I have a question that I can't seem to work out. Specifically, I don't entirely understand what is being asked.

The questions is:

Let $\mu_0$ be a premeasure on an algebra $\mathcal{A}$. Let $\mu^*$ be the outer measure induced from $\mu_0$ and let $\mu = \mu^*\mid_{\mathcal{M(A)}}.$ Let $\theta$ be the outer measure induced from $\mu$. We let $\mathcal{M}^*$ denote the $\sigma-$algebra of splitting sets for the outer measure $\mu^*$ which is not (yet) known to coincide with the $\sigma-$algebra of splitting sets of $\theta$.

a.) Prove that $\theta =\mu^*.$

b.) Suppose that $\mu_0$ is $\sigma-$finite. Prove that $\mu^*\mid_{\mathcal{M^*}}$ equals the completion of $\mu$.

I don't entirely understand what the question is asking. Does $\mathcal{M(A)}$ denote the splitting sets of $\mu^*$?  So if $\theta(E) = \inf\lbrace \mu^*(A): E\subseteq A; A\in \mathcal{M(A)}\rbrace$, are we looking for the sets that satisfy the splitting condition for $\theta?$ Presumably these would align with $\mathcal{M(A)}$ correct? Would this be enough to prove the first part? I'm not really sure how to do the second part.

Thanks!

Comment: if you dont know what means $\mathcal{M(A)}$ then I dont know either. It seems that $\mu$ is the measure induced by $\mu^*$, anyway it is not so clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set $\mathcal{M(A)}$ denotes the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal A$. There is a result which assures that $\mu^*|_\mathcal{M(A)}$ is a measure.

The point of the exercise is to generalize the equivalence of three different approachs for the construction of the Lebesgue measure, that we list below:

> **(1)** Consider the premeasure $m$, defined on the algebra $\mathcal I$ of the intervals of $\mathbb R$, by $$m([a,b])=m((a,b])=m([a,b))=m((a,b))=b-a,$$
> then consider the outer measure $m^*$ generated by $m$ and define the Lebesgue measure to be the restriction $m^*|_{\mathcal M^*}$, where $\mathcal M^*$ denotes the $\sigma$-algebra of splitting sets for $m^*$.

We have that $\mu=m^*|_{\mathcal{M(I)}}$ is a measure (this fact holds for any premeasure). Note that $\mathcal{M(I)}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra of the borelian sets and that $\mu$ is the Jordan measure. The other two approaches are:

> **(2)** Consider the outer measure $\mu^*$, generated by $\mu$, and define the Lebesgue measure to be the restriction $\mu^*|_{\mathcal N^*}$, where $\mathcal N^*$ denotes the $\sigma$-algebra of splitting sets for $\mu^*$.
>
> **(3)** Define the Lebesgue measure to be the completion of $\mu$.

By the item $a)$ of the exercise, that $\mu^*=m^*$, then so it does $\mathcal N^*=\mathcal M^*$, and consequently, $\mu^*|_{\mathcal N^*}=m^*|_{\mathcal M^*}$, which proves the equivalence of $(1)$ and $(2)$. Then, item $b)$ proves that $(3)$ is equivalent to $(1)$.

The exercise proves that these three approaches are equivalent for any premeasure in any algebra, given that the premeasure is $\sigma$-finite.

Let us prove item a) of the exercise, then item b) follows from item a) and the fact that the restriction of $\theta$ to the $\sigma$-algebra of the splitting sets for $\theta$ is the completion of $\mu$.

Suppose that $\mathcal A$ is an algebra in $X$. For any $A\in \mathcal A$, we have that $A\in\mathcal{M(A)}$ and $\mu_0(A)=\mu^*(A)$. Fix $E\subset X$. For any $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subset \mathcal A$ covering $E$, we have, in particular, that $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subset \mathcal{M(A)}$, then, by the definition of $\theta$,
$$
\theta(E) \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu^*(A_n) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu_0(A_n).
$$
Then
$$
\theta(E) \leq \inf\left\{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu_0(A_n) : \mbox{$(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subset \mathcal A$ covers $E$}\right\} = \mu^*(E).
$$
It lasts to prove that $\mu^*(E)\leq \theta(E)$.

Fix $\varepsilon>0$ and pick $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subset \mathcal{M(A)}$ covering $E$ such that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu^*(A_n)\leq \theta(E)+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}.
$$
By the definition of $\mu^*$, for each $A_n$, there exists $(B^n_j)_{j\in\mathbb N}\subset \mathcal A$ covering $A_n$ such that
$$
\sum_{j=1}^\infty \mu_0(B^n_j)\leq\mu^*(A_n)+\frac{\varepsilon}{2^{n+1}}.
$$
Then, $(B^n_j)_{(n,j)\in\mathbb N\times\mathbb N} \subset \mathcal A$ covers $E$, so
$$
\mu^*(E)\leq\sum_{(n,j)\in\mathbb N\times\mathbb N} \mu_0(B^n_j) \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu^*(A_n) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\varepsilon}{2^{n+1}} \leq \theta(E) + \varepsilon. 
$$
Since this is valid for every $\varepsilon>0$, it follows that
$\mu^*(E)\leq\theta(E)$.

Comment: Andre, thank you for this helpful answer. In this problem set I’ve proved the following result: Let (X,M,μ) be a σ-finite measure space, and let μ∗ be the outer measure induced from μ, with splitting sets M∗. Prove that μ∗|M∗ is the completion of μ. (Hint: use problem 1.). If I could show that $\theta$ = $\mu^*$, then the result in b follows immediately, correct? How would I prove part a? In particular, what is required to show thy two measures are equal? That they agree at every set in some sigma algebra? Which one? What would be your solution? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, by the result you mentioned, we have that $\theta|_{\mathcal N}$ is the completion of $\mu$, where $\mathcal N$ denotes the $\sigma$-algebra of the splitting sets for $\theta$. Once it is proved that $\theta=\mu^*$, then we have that $\mathcal N=\mathcal M^*$, and consequently $\theta|_{\mathcal N}=\mu^*|_{\mathcal M^*}$.

Comment: Two measures are equal if they are defined at the same $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal M$ and coincide at every element of $\mathcal M$.

Comment: Perharps the detail here is that $\theta$ and $\mu^*$ are not measures. They are outer measures. Suppose that $\mathcal A$ is an algebra in $X$. Then, they are defined for any $E\subset X$. They are equal if they coincide at every $E\subset X$.

Comment: In particular, since $\theta(E) = \inf\lbrace \mu^*(A) :  A\subseteq E\; A\subseteq \mathcal{M(A)}\rbrace$, and $\mu^*(E) = \inf \lbrace \mu_0(A) : A\subseteq E\; A\subseteq \mathcal{A}\rbrace$. They at least correspond on the algebra $\mathcal{A}$. My thought is to use the $\pi -\lambda$ theorem but I'm not sure how I would use it.

Comment: I just added the solution of a) to the answer. Check it out.

Comment: Andre, thank you.

Comment: I’ve looked at your solution and it makes a lot of sense. I’ve noticed in measure theory that equality is frequently proved as estimates on either side and I think that I will have to study this technique in more detail

Comment: Yes! This technique with the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{2^n}$ is pretty useful.